# What Java library can I use to process WSDL files?

Tags: java, xml, frameworks, wsdl, soa

In SOA, I can send a WSDL file to SOA application server that will return an XML response.

I want to create a simple Java application that can receive a WSDL file, process it, and return XML response.

Is there a free Java library or framework that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

recommend you to use wsdl4j. It provides a lot of API for you to do the operation. http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/

Answer (score 1):

Yes all you need is a SOAP stack.

There are verygood opensource framework choices like [Apache AXIS](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) , [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)

- Using WSDL with Axis : [Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#UsingWSDLWithAxis)
- With CXF : [Guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/defining-contract-first-webservices-with-wsdl-generation-from-java.html)

Comment: _As a side note:_ as for Axis it would be better to point to the [Axis 2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) page (and [guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide.html)), not 1, because Axis1 can be considered outdated (last release was made in 2006), unless the OP wants it for a project that needs to use JAX-RPC...